# what is the meaning of word 'ghost' here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

the tough tissues surrounding the actual brain -- as well as tiny capillaries and portions of adjacent cortical tissues have been preserved as mineralised 'ghosts'.
What is the meaning of 'ghosts' here ?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ghost

Look at definition 4.a: "a faint shadowy trace."

The way a person leaves behind a ghost, the dinosaur's brain tissue left behind a fossil.